# @GeneratedValue annotation is not generated by Intellij PersistenceFramework

Tags: hibernate, intellij-idea, reverse-engineering

I'm developing my web application on Spring Framework, Hibernate, and PostgreSQL.
I use Intellij IDEA.

Using reverse engineering, I wish to generate domain class.
Yes, we can generate domain class using IDEA Persistence Framework.
But! It's not generate @GeneratedValue annotation for AI column.

I did reverse engineering for MySQL too. In that case, same.

Why?

Comment: @GeneratedValue is a javax.persistence library

Comment: Yes, I use Spring Data JPA.